# How to access locale qualified drawable in android

Tags: android, locale, android-drawable

I tried to make separate drawable for different locale e.g. french_flag, german_flag, etc.
What i did was, in the android studio project structure i made a folder with "drawable-<qualifier>" format so it's like drawable-fr, drawable-de. After that i put the specific flag image png. I also put usa_flag.png in the main drawable folder as default locale.

When i load usa_flag.png by accessing it with `R.drawable.usa_flag`, it worked fine. But when i tried to access the `R.drawable.french_flag` it always throws unsolved reference on compile time.

I searched in google and it says I can't access qualified drawable resources directly through `R.drawable.xxxx`, i need to use `context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx)` but this method also doesn't works and threw out the same error.

I also used `context.resources.getIdentifier("french_flag", "drawable", context.packageName)`, this helped me get through the unsolved reference compile time error, but when I change the locale inside my app using `Locale.setDefault()`, it throws similar error : `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, in order to solve the issue you have to make sure that the drawable has the same file name on each drawable- folder.

For instance, when talking about flags, all the drawable folders such as `drawable-fr`, `drawable-es`, etc has the same flag.png (or svg) picture and from the code you access the flag with `context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.flag)`.

Once you change the locale from the phone's settings then the app will automatically pick the correct flag.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was indeed the image need to be the same name.